# Connect a value to duration parameter of a Delay Patch in Spark AR

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

How do I link a number to the duration parameter in the Delay Patch? There is no connection option in the default Patch.

Image: https://i.ibb.co/1LdTCx4/Captura-de-Pantalla-2020-07-29-a-la-s-11-37-19.png

I want to connect my DelayDuration value to the duration parameter of the Delay Patch.

Answer (score 0):

so before we could do it but now we cant do that . that was a bug that allowed changing the values via other patch but now it will not work .